# What is this screw's name / type?

Tags: screws

Seems that recently Ikea and many other menufacturers are using the screw you see in picture (classic 1.5 multi power plug, nothing fancy).

I have never seen anything similar and searching online didn't help much.

Can you please suggest its name so that I can buy a specific tool to unscrew it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a rivet to me (not meant to be removed).

Comment: I don't think it is a rivet... It is more similar to those weird hair dryer screws (normal screw but the head has two "dots") except this one has 3 dots.

Comment: If that's the case it's likely a proprietary fastener and has no name--just a corporate part number.

Comment: I would agree but now it seems very common in similar products. This is the product (not to be specific but just to give idea, it should 100% be openable): https://www.ikea.com/nl/en/p/koppla-4-way-socket-with-2-usb-ports-white-90280826/ I went around in shops and 2 other vendors have the same identical screw... Seems like a new standard to me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one version of a security screw, there are several types.

Used to try to make items not easily opened by the masses so you have to buy another instead of fixing something simple...

Depending on how deep they are I have used needle nose pliers or made a "socket" for them - I see those as a challenge and have boxes of "ordinary" screws to replace them.

Comment: I agree with @isherwood they are a proprietary type of tamper resistant or safety / security screw I checked my big set and it is not in that.  But a left handed drill bit or needle nose pliers may be the way to remove them, I have also greased the hole and used epoxy in the past but that was a very expensive part , I had 6 locations , epoxy works but you have to have a nice thin film of grease in the bottom and on the sides or you make a really nasty plug. Once the epoxy cures the screw backs out, but with these the divot is not that big epoxy may not work.